# Modifying the OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'd like to modify the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` which is created by the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` configuration in Spring Boot 1.3.2. As far as I can tell, the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` class is constructed internally without any application context wiring. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is the best way of doing it, but you can do this with a BeanPostProcessor:

```
public static class DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof FilterChainProxy) {

                FilterChainProxy chains = (FilterChainProxy) bean;

                for (SecurityFilterChain chain : chains.getFilterChains()) {
                    for (Filter filter : chain.getFilters()) {
                        if (filter instanceof OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter) {
                            OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter = (OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter) filter;
                            oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter
                                    .setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return bean;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How exactly would you include `DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor`? I tried making an `@Bean public DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor defaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor() { }`, but I get the following exception on start-up. `IllegalStateException: ObjectPostProcessor is a required bean. Ensure you have used @EnableWebSecurity and @Configuration`

Comment: We have a static bean method in one of the "@Configuration" annotated classes to create it, as the post processor needs to be created before any of the other beans are:

@Bean
    public static DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor defaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor() {
        return new DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor();
    }