# How to redirect after login to a specific uri in spring boot auth2 facebook

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am following this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

I can't figure out how to redirect to my let's say html page after successful login.

Here is my starting point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SimpleApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }
}
```

Here is my application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: id
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

I've tried adding below to **configure** method but it only creates more problems with missing dependency and then with missing bean and so on

```
.and()
.oauth2Login().defaultSuccessUrl("/after");
```

Can someone advice?

Comment: Take a look at this answer[this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617718/modifying-the-oauth2clientauthenticationprocessingfilter-in-spring-boot?rq=1). It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no property in spring security auto configuration, So you need to init the filter yourself, and set the success handler in it, here is the link in [github](https://github.com/chao-luo/stackoverflow/tree/Q54958335)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class StackOverflowApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/after");
    }


    private OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter() {
        OAuth2SsoProperties sso = (OAuth2SsoProperties)this.getApplicationContext().getBean(OAuth2SsoProperties.class);
        OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = ((UserInfoRestTemplateFactory)this.getApplicationContext().getBean(UserInfoRestTemplateFactory.class)).getUserInfoRestTemplate();
        ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices = (ResourceServerTokenServices)this.getApplicationContext().getBean(ResourceServerTokenServices.class);
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(sso.getLoginPath());
        filter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
        filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        filter.setApplicationEventPublisher(this.getApplicationContext());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackOverflowApplication.class, args);
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                ;
        http.addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), LogoutFilter.class);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also retrieve the spring pre-configured filter and change its properties:

```
@EventListener
public void retrieveAuthenticationFilter(ApplicationStartedEvent event){
    FilterChainProxy filterChain = (FilterChainProxy) event.getApplicationContext().getBean(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
    filterChain.getFilterChains().stream()
            .map(f -> f.getFilters())
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .filter(f -> f.getClass().isAssignableFrom(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class))
            .map(f -> (OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter)f)
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(this::configureAuthenticationFilter);
}

private void configureAuthenticationFilter(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter authenticationFilter){
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setUseReferer(true);
    authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
}
```